# Hibernate: Intermediate relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have problems to solve this relationship between User and Roles.

I was able to resolve the relations between User-Organization and Organization-Roles

How can I solve it using notations?

**EDIT**

I have these classes:

Organization Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Organizations")
public class Organization implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String imgLogo;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
         name = "OrganizationRoles",
         joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "organizationId", 
             referencedColumnName = "id", updatable = false)},
         inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "roleId", 
             referencedColumnName = "id", updatable = false)}
    )
    private List<Role> roles;

    ....
}
```

User Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    private String name;    

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "organizationId", nullable = false)
    private Organization organization;

    ????????
    private List<Role> roles;
    ...
}
```

Thank you!

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYGdK.png)

Comment: Please provide what you have done so far to solve your problem.

Comment: Looks alright. What's the problem? you should carefully configure shown refs.

Comment: Edited with classes